# VB.net 2017 Change background color of button

Tags: vb.net

I just started using vb.net 2017 instead of the 2010 version and i can't figure out how to change the background color of a button. I used to be able to do

```
`but1.BackColor = Colors.Blue`
```

But it seems as if BackColor isn't available anymore. What could be a possible solution?

Edit: added screenshots

[Form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ydO.png) VS auto corrects color to ColorInterpolationMode
[Designer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJUhI.png)

Comment: Have you accidentally started a different project than WinForms? Does `but1.Background` exist? If so then you've started a WPF project rather than a WinForms project.

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot of the entire form/window designer?

Comment: I started it as a Blank App (Universal Windows), the only other options are Class Library (Universal Windows), Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows), and Unit Test App (Universal Windows). I edited my post to have a screenshot of the designer and the form code. @Visual Vincent

Answer (score 1):

UWP is a completely different framework than WinForms (Windows Forms). If you want the standard WinForms library for desktop applications (which was what you were using in VS 2010) try [**downloading VS 2017 again**](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15) and make sure you install the standard set of items/packages.

If you want to change the background color of a button in UWP you gotta use the `Background` property. Try this:

```
but1.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me, I just tried this myself and works fine in VS 2017.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm1ur.png)

Check btn1 properties under 'Apperance' If you dont see BackColor there that might help point you into the right direction. Don't think is a VS 2017 issue.

Comment: Under 'Apperance' there's only Opacity, Visibility, RequestedTheme. To change the color in the designer I use Brush > Background > Solid Color Brush in the Properties window. In my high school class we used VS 2010 and `Button1.BackColor = Color.Blue` worked for me then.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I had the wrong version of VS installed... I had "Universal Windows Platform development", I reinstalled VS using the ".NET desktop development" version. This solves a lot of other problems I've had in the past also!

Comment: Darn, my phone is too slow ;). Well I wrote an answer explaining how you can change the background color in UWP as well.

Comment: Haha thanks for the help @Visual Vincent, I almost gave up on VS!